# Exterior power representation of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $V = \left\{x \in \mathbb C^n \mid x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = 0 \right\} \subset\mathbb C^n$. We know that $V$ is an irreducible representation of $S_n$. Why is the representation $\Lambda^k(V)$ irreducible for all $k$ with $1\leq k\leq n-1$?

Comment: If I remember correctly, $\Lambda^k\left(V\right)$ is the Specht module corresponding to one of the hook partitions of $n$ -- perhaps $\left(k+1,1,1,\ldots,1\right)$ (with $n-k$ parts) or its transpose.

Comment: Ah, Exercise 4.3.5 in [Martin Lorenz, *A Tour of Representation Theory*, preliminary version of October 29, 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20171106232950/https://www.math.temple.edu/~lorenz/ToR.pdf) (now [published as a book by AMS, in the GSM series](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/a-tour-of-representation-theory)). Would be great if someone writes up a proper answer, though; this is too often left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a general fact that if $W$ is a finite (complex) reflection group with irreducible reflection representation $V$ then the exterior powers $\Lambda^i(V)$ are all irreducible. If $W$ can be generated by $\mathrm{dim}(V)$ reflections, then this is the content of exercise 3. to §2 of Chapter 5 of Bourbaki's book *Lie groups and Lie algebras*, a fact which Bourbaki credits to Steinberg (this already answers your question, modulo the exercise and the fact that the symmetric group is such a reflection group). The general case is a corollary: any irreducible reflection group contains a subgroup that is generated by $\mathrm{dim}(V)$ reflections and which still acts irreducibly on $V$.